# IBM Worklight Adaptor not able to convert French text response from back end services correctly

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

We found that IBM worklight ( 6.2.0.00 ) adaptor is not able to properly convert input xml with French characters in JSON. some characters such as  "numéro" are changing to "num~Aro" (Actually 'A' with '~' character over it)

We have no issue when return type from back end system is JSON having french characters.

We don't get above issue on developer machine but with QA environment which is set on Linux Box.

Are we missing any configuration setting ?

Comment: You say that in the developer machine this conversion works, but in the QA environment it does not work. So it does not seem like it's an adapter inability... what is different between the two machines?

Comment: Developers are not able to reproduce it in eclipse environment but our QA server is on Linux box running license version of worklight. I am not facing the problem with services that returns JSON but for one that returns XML, The back end services are same in both the case.

Answer (score 0):

see http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_5.0.6/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/apiref/r_method_wl_server_invokehttp.html

try to specify returnedContentEncoding

Answer (score 0):

We found the solution to our issue.
We have to enabled multiple language support of JVM Encoding in Websphare.

By Setting the “Generic JVM argumments” to be.
-Dclient.encoding.override=UTF-8 -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
Apply the changes and save the configuration. Also we require to restart the server